# Deadlock on Wpf Main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, deadlock

I've got a wpf application that sometimes when a high frequency grid is updated it goes in deadlock on another thread that is updating a list of.
The high frequency gird is updated via band get to an ObservableCollection, while the other thread that updates the list is updated via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
How can avoid the kind of deadlock? Wasn't binding supposed to be safe?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your data calls asynchronous?

Comment: Is there only one background thread?

Comment: Band ... is that devexpress ? anyway, it's almsot not possible to figure what cause your problem by your description only. But, here's my few "guess". 1st, you also need to make sure your background update of ObservableCollection has to be done in MainThread. 2nd, trigger a "Pause" debug when you're having deadlock. Good chance that you'll see the debug stop at a code that's performing GUI update and then find out which other thread is blocking at that moment in order to narrow down your search.

Comment: _"Wasn't binding supposed to be safe?"_ -- I don't even know what that's supposed to mean. Data binding generally is thread-ignorant; i.e. it has no support built in for multi-threaded code, never mind was intended to solve all multi-threading problems, like deadlock. In any case, your question is unanswerable without a good [mcve]. If you've deadlocked the thread, the obvious answer is "don't do that". It is possible you are simply updating the data too often, which can saturate the UI thread and make it appear unresponsive. But absent a good code example, there are too many possible answers.

Comment: I agree with Peter, anyway PropertyChanged events are marshalled at UI level, therefore there's no need to manually invoke the Dispatcher, just add your elements to your collection and let WPF do its job. Though I don't think this is the cause of the deadlock, please give use more information and also some code to test, otherwise it's hard to help.